# How to structure s3 bucket for access control

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I know that this could be a trivial problem but I think is important to do things in the right way.

We have an internal application that is used by 80 users now and we want to migrate our storage to s3.

We have 3 environments: dev, test, prod and I was thinking on s structure like this:

- dev

  - user-1
  - ...
  - user-n

    - assets (profile picture, other public data)
    - generated documents (private)
- test
- prod

In this part we have 3 user rights (ROLE_USER, ROLE_TEAMLEAD, ROLE_ADMIN). Who has role of user should be able to access only his/she's objects, who has role of teamleader can access also all the documents of his team, and who has ADMIN can access all the documents.

What is the safest way to design this, so that when I make a call after an object and a userId/username to get back all the objects that belong to that person.

Should here be a good idea to create groups (should also be easy to update if a teamlead leaves, or if a user changes his/she's teamlead) and also to have aws accounts for all our users?
Any idea/good material will help, thanks.

Comment: How do you intend to authorize access to S3 assets for these 3 sets of users? Using IAM policies or application-level authorization logic?

Comment: What if at some point you wanted to provide "shareable" files so users can view files in a different user directory? -- If this is going to require fine tuned perms, I would map these users to a DB, as well as their uploaded files, and then assign access rights more cleanly from the DB

Comment: @jarmod i was thinking on IAM

Comment: @ViaTech I was thinking on this. If I will do so the logic will become complicated and I want to see some opinions if this can be avoided and handled by aws

Comment: Is the relationship between users and teams strictly 1:1, or can a user belong/lead multiple teams?

Comment: Are the users of this system actually AWS IAM users (I presume not)? Or do they authenticate to your system directly to gain access to the files, or via federation such as Cognito, ADFS, etc?

Comment: @sytech mapping is one to one. One user can have only one teamlead

Comment: @jarmod users are not IAM users. They are in a mariaDB. They will use my system that will ask for files aws

Comment: If the number of users and teams is going to be small, then you could potentially create one IAM role per user and one IAM role per team. The AWS soft limit on roles is 1000. Each user IAM role would have a policy allowing access to `arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>/<userid>/`. Each team IAM role has a policy allowing access to all the S3 ARNs or the team users. The admin role allows access to the entire bucket. Your app then assumes the IAM role relevant to the user, team lead, or admin. As users and teams are modified in your app, you'd have to maintain the roles in sync. Note: there are no IAM users.

Comment: But you'd have to do due diligence on the quotas for IAM roles, policies, and policy sizes. This is not actually a commonly-used solution in my experience because of IAM quotas but it could work in a small environment. The advantage of it is that you are leveraging IAM roles and policies  as an additional security layer, rather than writing custom authorization, which is powerful.

Answer (score 1):

If your users are IAM (or cognito) users, the structure you have can't accomplish the access control goals with static policies. If you're able to update the IAM policies when membership changes, then the structure *can* work.

Your IAM policy condition for regular users or admins would be pretty simple to meet the objectives. Each user accessing their own bucket can be allowed by a bucket policy allowing the S3 actions conditioned on the key prefix being their username (`${aws:Username}` policy variable). Granting access for admins can be done through a group policy on the admin group.

The problem is you have is with the team lead roles. Here, you have two dimensions of access: user and role, but the file structure contains just one of those pieces of information -- you can't determine which objects should belong to a particular teamlead role by the object structure alone. That is, you can't construct a group/bucket policy that grants access according to the requirements without knowing all the usernames in that group (since directories are organized by user only).

This could be fixed if you organized your structure by nesting users within team directories:

- team1
- - user1
- - user2
- team2
- - user3
- - user-N

Then you could apply a group policy for each teamlead group to allow access objects under the team directory for the respective team. The IAM policy would not have to change when teamleads or team members change. This is also consistent with the [Controlling access to a bucket with user policies guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/walkthrough1.html).

However, this implies a strictly one-to-one relationship between users and teams, which may not be the case for you. And, if users change teams, they'll need their directory in S3 moved.

Alternatively, using the structure you propose, you could generate IAM policies based on group membership at a moment in time, specifying all the users directories belonging to a particular team in the policy. However, whenever the group membership changes, the policy will have to change, too.

---

As an aside, you may also want to consider using separate buckets for your different environments instead of top level directories. That way, you can effectively test changes that affect the entire bucket (like applying bucket policies) independently for each environment.